# Cannot open OpenCL Settings in Cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape

When I clicked on Edit > Preferences > OpenCl Settings, nothing happens. I tried reinstalling Cytoscape, but this did not solve the problem.

The Cytoscape task history states "Untitled (org.cytoscape.opencl.cycl.CyCLSettingsTask)".

Here's some specs and other info:

**Specs:**

Operating System: Windows 10

CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor
3.60 GHz

Installed RAM: 64.0 GB

GPU: RTX 3070

System type: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

**Information in "About Cytoscape":**

Version: 3.9.1

Java: 11.0.6 by AdoptOpenJDK

Java Home: c:\program files\common files\i4j_jres\11.0.6

OS: Windows 10 10.0 - amd64

Comment: A dialog pops up for me running Cytoscape 3.9.1 on a Mac. Maybe provide your specs to help narrow the troubleshooting?

Comment: I just added them!

Comment: Thanks. Also curious about your version of Cytoscape and Java.

Comment: I just added these too.

Comment: Great. I submitted a bug report with the Cytoscape dev team. It will be discussed on Thursday. I'll post any answers here.

Comment: We have reproduced the same behavior on a Windows machine, so that's a good lead. Stay tuned...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the CyCL app (https://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/cycl), which is distributed pre-loaded with Cytoscape. A bug report has been filed and a new release will be made when fixed. Users will see a notification (bell in upper-right) with new versions of apps are available. Sorry for the trouble!

If curious, the gist of the issue is that while the app is scanning for local graphic devices to populate the combobox dialog, if it hits a NULL or error, then the whole dialog fails to load. The fix will be to simply skip those particular devices and list the others.