# Display Glitch + Unable to open OpenCL settings in Cytoscape 3.10.1 (Debian Bookworm)

Tags: cytoscape

I installed Cytoscape latest version in Debian Bookworm, as you can see here:
UserAgent = Cytoscape v3.10.1 Java 17.0.9 Linux 6.1.0-17-amd64
latestVersion = 3.10.1

After importing file using "File -> Import -> Network from file....", the display would glitch as seen below.[Glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxgrP.jpg). I got a consistent glitches twice.

As I think there's a problem related to the driver, I tried to open the OpenCL settings to see if I can change the platform. However, I could not open the OpenCL settings as also shown in this post [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71707271/cannot-open-opencl-settings-in-cytoscape).

Is there anything that I could do to solve the problem?

My PC specs: AMD Ryzen 5 5600X; NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER (Nvidia toolkit 11.8 +driver 520.X.X). Not the latest driver but other program depends on this old version of toolkit, so I don't plan to upgrade the driver.

Regards,

yam

tldr:
Major display glitch.Tried to openCL setting, but no windows appeared.
Glitch is persistent, I can only hardreset the system if it happened.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are right that there is an issue with the graphics driver, although the import network from file does not use OpenCL, so I don't think the problems are there.  If you run this from a shell, there should be some messages printed as it starts up that might give you some clues as to what's going on.  I run regularly on Fedora and currently using driver 545.29.06 and things seem to be working OK.